# What happens to ConnectyCube video conference meetings that were created but never used

Tags: javascript, sdk, connectycube

I am new to ConnectyCube API and have just learned how to create meetings for Video Conference calls. Is the meeting room destroyed after the specified end date?  What if meeting is set up without start or end date, does meeting expire after a certain period? I tried to get a list of meetings that were created under my developer account, but could only retrieve a list of meetings created during the same user session.

I expected to get all the list of meetings created under the same developer account, but could only retrieve list of meetings created during a given user session.  How can I get a list of all active meetings (whether or not occupied but available to be occupied)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not destroyed. The start/end time is solely for participants purpose, same to Google Meet.

The get a list of meetings:

```
const params = { limit: 5, offset: 0 };
ConnectyCube.meeting
  .get(params)
  .then((meetings) => {})
  .catch((error) => {});
```